# jquery drag sort chrome glitch

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I just implemented drag and drop sort table on my site

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/U22Bz/)

On chrome sometimes the rows border change colors specially the bottom one it turns black and its pretty buggy.

Works fine on IE and Firefox

I also notice that my row is very small when dragging and it's not the actual size of the of the row. Any work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that has to come because you do not use any **CSS Reset**...

and by the way, you should add `border-top: none;` to your `td, th` style right after you set the border, so you don't have border with `2px` as the `bottom` of one will be added to the `top` of the other creating lines with `2px`'s and not a smooth `1px` in every `tr`

Here is an updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/U22Bz/3/